# React Native send data from component to parent component that called it

Tags: javascript, ios, react-native

I'm working on a react native app that uses a timer component I made, the code for it is:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {
    Platform,
    StyleSheet,
    Text,
    TouchableOpacity,
    View
} from 'react-native';
import styles from '../styles/style';

export default class Timer extends Component<{}> {
    constructor(props) {
        super();
        this.state = {
            time: 10,
            timerStarted: false
        }
    }

    startTimer() {
        this.interval = setInterval(() => {
            this.setState({
                isFirstRender: !this.state.isFirstRender,
                time: this.state.time-1,
                isTimerRunning: true
            });
        }, 1000);
    }

    render() {
        if (!this.state.isTimerRunning)
            this.startTimer();

        return (
            <View style={styles.scoreBoard}>
                <Text style={styles.timerText}>Time: {this.state.time}</Text>
            </View>
        );
    }
}
```

This component has a state value, time, that counts down from 10, decrementing each second. When the timer reaches zero, I need it to somehow notify the component that called it when the timer is done. In my program my main js file is App.js, which calls my timer in its render function like this:

```
render () {

        return (
            <View style={{flex: 1, flexDirection: 'row'}}>
                <View style={{flex: 1}}>
                    {/*This below is the component I need to return a value to this main class we are in*/}
                    <MyTimer />
                </View>
            </View>
        );
    }
```

I need my Timer class to return a value, perhaps a boolean, to the main class indicating that the time is up. My best guess is that maybe I can send a member function of my main class to the Timer class as a prop, but I'm not sure if that's how this works. I've tried different ways of accomplishing this, and I know that you can use props to send data to a component, but how do you retrieve data from a component? Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You pass a function from parent to child then invoke it in the child to update the parent:

```
onTimerEnd = () => //do something in parent

render () {

        return (
            <View style={{flex: 1, flexDirection: 'row'}}>
                <View style={{flex: 1}}>
                    {/*This below is the component I need to return a value to this main class we are in*/}
                    <MyTimer onTimerEnd={this.onTimerEnd} />
                </View>
            </View>
        );
    }
```

Also I think you should start the timer in the constructor not in render, render will get called every time the component re-renders:

```
export default class Timer extends Component<{}> {
    constructor(props) {
        super();
        this.state = {
            time: 10,
        }
        this.startTimer(); //start timer
    }

    startTimer() {
        localTime = this.state.time;
        this.interval = setInterval(() => {
            this.setState({
                time: this.state.time-1,
            }, () => {
                if (this.state.time === 0) this.props.onTimerEnd() //invoke when timer hits 0
            });
        }, 1000);
    }

    render() {   
        return (
            <View style={styles.scoreBoard}>
                <Text style={styles.timerText}>Time: {this.state.time}</Text>
            </View>
        );
    }
}
```